# Closing Chrome main windows in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome

Is there a way to close just the main window of Chrome browser?

In my app when I click on a button a new Chrome window opens with a link on a local server and I generate a pdf file using php.

I wait until the file has been generated and then close that window.

At the moment I use a `PowerShell` command to do it but I would like to know if there is a faster easier way without using `Kill()` as I don't want to close all windows.

```
static void RunProcess(string filename, string arguments)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = filename;
    startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}

RunProcess("powershell.exe", "Get-Process chrome | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow()}");
```

Comment: `Process.Start()` returns a `Process` object you can later kill. However...do you really need to open Chrome to generate a PDF? wkhtmltopdf is pretty handy and easy to use.

Comment: At this point I realy do need to Chrome or any other browser to generate the pdf. I use TCPDF and fPDf to generate all sorts of labels and test results and then I automaticly send that PDF to the required printer/tray. I will look into wkhtmltopdf  for future reference.